# how to get paypal plan in react js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, paypal-sandbox

import paypal from "paypal-rest-sdk";

paypal.configure({
mode: "sandbox", // 'sandbox' or 'live'
client_id:
"AYz0v_Momlc2QHALE0O45ee_Dw769DKh4D6NZI9IUSEzeE3GdOfVKQmm66iQdhzCjHh2RCxoCIbKDc54",
client_secret:
"EO3sdFxGg81n2o6cqjSZVyu3EtppN0DzUmaIKCJ21h5yhx3f6S2yuV5Q9leMXFnCso3JZAqMSHthdM6S",
});

```
paypal.billingPlan.list({}, function (error, plans) {
  if (error) {
    console.log("error", error);
    // throw error;
  } else {
    console.log("plans", plans);
    // Do something with the plans here
  }
});
```

`Error: Invalid value for opts.mode`

how to handle this error

Comment: are you running ```paypal.billingPlan.list``` on server side or client side ?

Answer (score 0):

The billing plans API is deprecated, do not use it. The new PayPal [Subscriptions API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/) has its own plans.

All PayPal REST SDKs are deprecated and not maintained nor supported, do not use them.

---

You can create a Subscriptions plan via the account interface

- Sandbox: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/billing/plans
- Live: https://www.paypal.com/billing/plans

Or with your own REST API call (no SDK).

Any and all API calls (that require first using the clientid+secret to obtain an access token) should be done from the backend/server.

If you need some simple examples in node, see the [standard checkout integration guide](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server) for the checkout use case. These can be adapted to whatever Subscription API calls you wish to implement.

Comment: but I need to get all plans. how can achieve this?

Comment: If you are using Subscription Plans, see the Subscriptions API reference https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#plans_list

Comment: If you are using deprecating billing plans (why?), consider changing your integration

Comment: i am also using this and pass accessToken but i got 401 error